# Что значит третий параметр в функции UpdateResource()?

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть функция `UpdateResource()`, которая нужна для обновления ресурсов в файле. Но я не понимаю, что значит 3 параметр `lpName`? Из документации:

> Указатель на символьную строку с нулем в конце, определяющую имя обновляемого ресурса. Этим параметром может также быть целочисленное значение, переданное в макрос `MAKEINTRESOURCE`.

Я тут нашел пример, в котором используется именно макрос. В качестве параметра в этот макрос передается число 10. Я немного не понимаю, это - просто случайное число или оно что-то означает. Для чего этот параметр? С помощью него потом можно найти ресурс или что?

P.S. Пример взят из программы-криптора. Там идет запись ресурсов файла. То есть, по этому имени потом можно найти данный ресурс или что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это проявление [изобретательности](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610565/why-does-makeintresource-work) ребят из Microsoft.

```
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEA(i) (LPSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i)))
```

Макрос на самом деле кастит айдишник в указатель, но этот указатель никогда на венде не будет валидным (!). Но вот функции, которые работают с ресурсами, знают об этом факте и умеют корректно такое переваривать.

Таким образом, ресурсы можно идентифицировать по именам (которые обычные строки `ASCII-Z`), либо по вот таким айдишкам ( которых может быть максимум 64к )

Что касается вашего вопроса, 10 - это именно идентификатор ресурса. Его выбирает программист по своему желанию, и потом, где-то в коде, может им воспользоваться, чтобы найти ресурс.